# Python, how to get the next item out of an array (list) in a for loop

Tags: python, list

I have a array (list) with times and now I need to determine if the eclipsed time is between two successive times from this list.

```
duurSeq=[11,16,22,29]
nu = time.time()
verstreken_tijd = nu - starttijd
for t in duurSeq:
   if (verstreken_tijd > t ) and (verstreken_tijd < **t_next** ):
      doSomething():
```

my question is: How do I get t_next  (the next item in the array within the for loop)

Comment: start with the second entry and use t_vorige?

Comment: @percusse ty. nice suggestion, I go work on that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
duurSeq=[11,16,22,29]
for c, n in zip(duurSeq, duurSeq[1:]):
    if (verstreken_tijd > c) and (verstreken_tijd < n):
        doSomething():
```

---

Refer to [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python) for a general approach.

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

# Demo
l = [11, 16, 22, 29]
for c, n in pairwise(l):
    print(c, n)

# Output
(11, 16)
(16, 22)
(22, 29)
```

Comment: thank you, this one works like I needed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some pointer arithmetic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574159/c-pointer-arithmetic-in-python) for a great example.

TL/DR you can move to the next item in the array by telling the interpreter to move 1 block up the sizeof(int). Basically take the next integer in memory. This works only because you know the size of the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foor loop on index instead of element

```
duurSeq = [11,16,22,29]
nu = time.time()
verstreken_tijd = nu - starttijd

for t in range(len(duurSeq)-1):
   if verstreken_tijd > duurSeq[i] and verstreken_tijd < duurSeq[i+1]:
      doSomething():
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access index of array inside for loop.

```
for index, element in enumerate(duurSeq):
    # Use duurSeq[index] to access element at any position
```